# At what angle do $y=x^2$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ intersect at $(1,1)$?

Tags: calculus

Problem: at what angle do $y=x^2$ and $y=\sqrt{x}$ intersect at (1,1)?

Solution: As far as I know angle of intersection of 2 curves is the angle of intersection of their tangent lines. Also, coefficient before x in tangent line equals tangent of the angle between line and x-axis.

$$y=x^2 \rightarrow y'=2x=2 \rightarrow \tan a=2$$
$$ y=\sqrt{x} \rightarrow y'=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac12 \rightarrow \tan b=\frac{1}{2}$$

EDIT:

Hence, my angle $= \arctan(2) - \arctan(0.5)$. The new question: it there any way to simplify it?

Comment: $-\infty<\tan\theta<\infty$ for real $\theta$

Comment: Oh, right. Somehow I was thinking about arctan while writing tan.

Comment: you will find delete option just below your question

Comment: But the principal value of $\arctan x$ lies $\in [-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only identity $\tan\theta$ has to satisfy is  $$\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta$$

$\sec\theta$ is real, for any real value of $\tan\theta$

As $\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$

if the angle  of intersection  is $\theta$

$$\theta=\arctan 2-\arctan \frac12=\arctan\left(\frac{2-\frac12}{1+2\cdot\frac12}\right)=\arctan \frac34$$

Comment: In some presentations of analytic geometry, this subtraction formula for the tangent is automatically called in for finding the angle between a line of slope $m$ and another of slope $m'$.

Comment: @Lubin, agreed. I have just shown how it came. http://planetmath.org/anglebetweentwolines